# Laravel problem insert multiple images to session on multi-form

Tags: laravel, session, eloquent

I have multiple form that i followed on https://github.com/5balloons/multi-step-form-laravel, every input was going well except when i input the multiple images. It cannot inserted to session. I'm using multiple session object to insert that corresponds with each model. Here are my codes:

I tried various things and ends up with the object returns null when i used `dd()`

**View**

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="images">Foto-foto Properti</label>
       <input type="file" {{(!empty($secondaryImage->images)) ? "disabled" : ''}} id="images" name="images[]" required autofocus multiple>
          @if ($errors->has('images'))
              <span class="invalid-feedback" style="color:red" role="alert">
               <strong>{{ $errors->first('images') }}</strong>
                   </span>
           @endif
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function submitStep2(Request $request)
    {
        $property = $request->session()->get('property');

        $secondary = new Secondary();
        $secondaryImage = new SecondaryImage();

        $validated =  $request->validate([
            'no_listing' => 'required|string',
            'nama_marketing' => 'required|string',
            'address' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        // Secondary
        if(empty($request->session()->get('secondary'))) {
            $secondary->fill($validated);
            $request->session()->put('secondary', $secondary);
        } else {
            $secondary = $request->session()->get('secondary');
            $request->session()->put('secondary', $secondary);
        }

        // SecondaryImage
        if(!isset($secondaryImage->images)) {
            $imgreq = $request->validate([
                'images' => 'required',
                'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            ]);

            $gambar = $request->file('images');

            if($request->hasFile('images')) {

                foreach ($gambar as $img) {
                    $imgsname = date('YmdHis').'-'.$img->getClientOriginalName();
                    $pathimgs = $img->storeAs('public/filesSession', $imgsname);
                    $secondaryImage->images = $pathimgs;
                    $images[] = $imgsname;
                }
            }


            $secondaryImage = $request->session()->get('secondaryImage');
            // $secondaryImage->fill($imgreq);

            $request->session()->put('secondaryImage', $secondaryImage);
        }

        dd($request->session()->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.secondary.create.step3');
    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: It returns `'secondaryImage' => null` with this code. On the other shot there only one image that inserted to session, i have no idea

Comment: did the image got uploaded? if yes, do a dump before you save the name to DB and lets see what is there

Comment: No sir it can't be uploaded, i have 5 step form and this is the 2nd step so this only inserted to session. After 5th step there will be uploaded to DB

Comment: I am sorry maybe i dont understand your question enough, can you forget about the multistep of a thing and tell me what you want to do precisely, i will replicate it and solution for you here.

Comment: do you want to upload multiple images in a single form?

Comment: Yes exactly sir, so here is my 2nd step of multiple form, i already bought session data from previous session and i am going to upload multiple images via session right now but the result is unexpected

Comment: before i post my script here, please do dd($request->file('images')); to confirm that we have the array of images, after that i will post my script here

Comment: Good to go sir, i have 6 images to be uploaded. But it shouldn't be the images that store to session as it is the bad practice, usually i put the image path to session

Comment: do you mean you want to put the image name in a session after upload?

Comment: Yess that's the point i am talking about! Actually i'd like to put the image path in a session

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me on laravel 5.7

```
      $images= $request->file('images');
      if ($images!= null) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
          if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
           $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('whateverFolder');
           $getimageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $request->image->move(public_path('whateverFolder'), $getimageName);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: What does move function for? I think that wouldn't work as if you didn't put the code that upload the image path to session

Comment: the first upload goes to the storage file in laravel and after successful upload, the move function moves it the where you want it to be saved

Comment: Got this error sir
````Call to a member function move() on null````

Comment: before i can know what went wrong, can you check YOUR PROJECT NAME\storage\app to see if the temporary upload went through, because from the look of things, the $request->image was null

Comment: I have succeeded put the image path into session but only the last image path not all of them sir,  do you have any idea?

Comment: After i checked my storage folder i just realized that all of my images stored there for long time ago but only shown 1 image after i ````dd()````

Comment: it is a foreach loop, so definitely only the last will show with a dd because it means dump and die. Also only the last one will be inserted into the session as you didnt add a unique key to the session. so the next will obviously overwrite the former

Comment: Ah  i see, i guess my problem has been fixed right now. Thank you sir!

Comment: you are welcome, if the solution worked for you, please vote up, if it didnt, let me know so that i can remove it